# Difference between identical and non-identical objects in counting

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, combinations

If 5 gifts are to be given among 8 children:

a) if the gifts are identical (indistinguishable) and no child can receive more than 1 gift, there are $_8P_5$ ways

b) if the gifts are non-identical (distinguishable) there are $5!(_8P_5)$ ways

In a), the only order is that of the way the children receiving it, while in b), the distinguishability of the objects adds another order.

Can someone tell me if my reasoning and calculations are correct?

Comment: Your answer also includes the order in which the children are given the gifts, but if you give one of $5$ indistinguishable gift to a given $5$ children, it doesn't matter who got their gift first. Likewise, if you give distinguishable toys $p,q,r,s,t$ to children $a,b,c,d,e$ (respectively), it again doesn't matter who got their gift first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not correct. Use combinations rather than permutations in your formulas.

(a) $_8C_5$

(b) $5!(_8C_5)$

*ps*:

I have presumed that even for (b), no child can receive more than one gift, the only difference from (a) being that the gifts are distinguishable.